# using createStackNavigator getting error : null is not an object (evaluating 't(r(d[1])).default.direction')

Tags: react-native

createStackNavigator is giving error :

`null is not an object (evaluating 't(r(d[1])).default.direction')`

Not able to get is this error because of an import statement or anything else. Any help will be appreciated

My code for app.js is below:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Home from './screens/Home';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LoginScreen: { screen: Login },
  HomeScreen: { screen: Home }
});

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

getting error:

[image]

Comment: which version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: react-navigation@3.9.1

Comment: Have you run "react-native link react-native-gesture-handler" ?

Comment: @Arnab did you find a solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'
```

and wrap the StackNav with it like:

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
```

In your `App` Component instead of `<AppNavigator/>`, set `<AppContainer/>`.